# Not correct to say that lean community is mostly mathematicians

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed Guy Coder made a number of edits to a lot of tags.  I accepted them all since overall they were much better, but on the same time in a number of them he suggested that lean (especially Lean community) is mostly mathematicians.  I'm not sure this is exactly true, and moreover might make others feel excluded.  Many in the community probably aren't even in academics.  And those who are can be mathematicians, computer scientists, philosophers, etc.  (These titles are arbitrary anyway especially when it comes to new areas of research like proof assistants.)

Is there a better way to phrase this?

The tags are still being approved.  Also, I would have contacted Guy Coder directly or commented on his changes, but I don't really know how to do that on this site.

Comment: I think that there are extremely senior people in the Lean community who are desperately trying to discredit the "Lean users are mostly mathematicians" belief because they believe it stifles community growth. I would certainly be voting for "don't say in public that most Lean users are mathematicians" option if I had a clue about what tags were etc (note: I'm not asking what tags are, I'm happy in my ignorance)

Comment: I should mention that I believe this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 6):

> "Also, I would have contacted Guy Coder directly or commented on his changes, but I don't really know how to do that on this site."

I highly recommend joining the [Theorem Provers chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133963/proof-assistants). Guy Coder is very active there, along with myself and others. You can ping people who have been in the room recently, by typing @ followed by the person's username with all spaces in the username removed.

I agree that tag descriptions do not need to say things like "mostly mathematicians".  I would approve edits to that tag wiki which significantly improve the description.